# Why doesn't assigning to the iteration variable in a foreach loop change the underlying data?

Tags: java, foreach

How come the following prints boss and not bass?

```
String boss = "boss";
char[] array = boss.toCharArray();

for(char c : array)
{
 if (c== 'o')
     c = 'a'; 
}
System.out.println(new String(array)); //How come this does NOT print out bass?It prints boss.
```

Comment: @KacyRaye by the way, this is a similar behavior when using the enhanced `for` loop on object references classes (and the solution proposed here is the same).

Answer (score 82, accepted):

You're changing the iteration variable `c`. That doesn't change the contents of the array. The iteration variable is just a *copy* of the array element. If you want to modify the array, you need to do so explicitly:

```
for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    if (array[i] == 'o') {
        array[i] = 'a';
    }
}
```

Your original code is equivalent (as per [section 14.14.2 of the JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.14.2)) to:

```
for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    char c = array[i];
    if (c == 'o') {
        c = 'a'; 
    }
}
```

Changing the value of a local variable will never change anything else - it *just* changes the local variable. The assignment:

```
char c = array[i];
```

*copies* the value in the array into a local variable. It doesn't associate the local variable with the array element perpetually.

Comment: Oh okay thanks.
I didn't understand that c was merely a copy.
Thanks that makes sense now.

Comment: @BaroudiSafwen: A copy of the array element *is* made at each iteration. What do you mean by "deform" here? I'm very confused as to what you're saying.

Answer (score 9):

This is because `c = 'a'` is assigning `a` to the local variable `c` which is not referencing the actual value present at that index of the `array` itself. It is just containing a copy of the value present at the specified index of `array`. So the change is actually made in the local variable not in the actual location where `array[i]` is referencing..
If you want to change value you should use the following indeed:

```
int i = 0;
for(char c : array)
{
 if (c== 'o')
     array[i] = 'a'; 
  i++;
}
```

Comment: At that point wouldn't you be better off using a normal for loop?

Answer (score 4):

c's value is a copy of the value in array. Access array directly to change the value in question.

Answer (score 3):

You variable `c` gets changed, but not the array contents.  To change the array, don't use `c`, manipulate the array directly.

```
for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
{
 char c = array[i];
 if (c== 'o')
     array[i] = 'a';
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You're assigning 'a' to the local variable c, but not to the array element. To make it print bass, you'd need

```
for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    if (array[i] == 'o') {
        array[i] = 'a';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Changes applied in 'for each' loop are made just inside her body (that's because values are copied, not referentions). To work on referentions use 'for' loop.