# Why are int matrices not immutable?

Tags: java, matrix, foreach, mutable

I was under the impression that primitive data values are immutable and thus could not be changed (focusing on enhanced for loops), that explains why this code doesn't work as intended:

```
//Not Mutable Primitaves
    int[] arr = new int[4];
    arr[0] = 1;
    arr[1] = 2;
    arr[2] = 3;
    arr[3] = 4;

    for(int i : arr){
        i = i*2;
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
        System.out.print(arr[i] + ",");
    }

    System.out.print("\n");
```

This Code continues to print 1,2,3,4 regardless of the multiplier. But in this code the enhanced for loop actually modifies the the original matrix but I have no idea why?

```
    public static void changeArr(int[] arr, int mult){
        for(int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
            arr[i] = arr[i] * mult;
        }
    }

    public static void main(){
    int[][] matrix = new int [3][3];

    for (int i = 0; i<matrix.length; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j<matrix[i].length; j++){
            matrix[i][j] = i;
        } 
    }

    for (int[] row : matrix){
        changeArr(row, 1);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i<matrix.length; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j<matrix[i].length; j++){
            System.out.print(matrix[i][j] + ",");
        } 
        System.out.print("\n");
    }
    }
```

Can someone help clarify why this works for the matrix but not the array?

*EDIT*
Doing arr[i] would crash the program with values such as:

```
    arr[0] = 1243;
    arr[1] = 21;
    arr[2] = 354;
    arr[3] = 4123;
```

Comment: In your first example, in the for loop, you are only dealing with the local variable `i`, and not updating the array.

Comment: try for(int i : arr){
        arr[i] = i*2;
    }

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15844443/why-java-foreach-doesnt-change-element-value

Comment: @RedCricket That will most likely index-out-of-bounds really quickly.

Comment: You seem to confuse the concepts of "value" and "variable". A line like `i = i*2` is only assigning to a variable; it has nothing to do with the value being mutable or immutable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for(int i : arr){
    i = i*2;
}
```

is equivalent to

```
for (int index = 0; index < arr.length; index++) {
   int i = arr[index];
   i = i * 2;
}
```

...which, as you can see, does nothing.  In contrast, for the two-dimensional array, what you get is

```
 for (int index = 0; index < matrix.length; index++) {
   int[] row = matrix[index];
   changeArr(row, 1);
 }
```

which works because `row` is a reference to the same object.

If you tried to set `row = newRow`, that would similarly do nothing, but you can modify the *contents* of row just fine.

Use normal indexed for loops and everything will work fine.

Comment: So is there any way to modify a primitive array with an enhanced for loop? I'm stating to study for the AP comp sci test and I want to cover all my bases. Thanks!

Comment: Not by assigning to the variable you're looping over.