# Access stream data within forEach

Tags: java, lambda

I am trying to create an int array and assign it random values. But when i print the values of the array, all the values are 0.

```
 int[] data = new int[1000000];
 Random r = new Random();
 Arrays.stream(data).forEach((x) -> {x = r.nextInt();});
 Arrays.stream(data).forEach(System.out::println);
```

How do i access values of array elements within forEach ?

Comment: This is the same problem as discussed in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15844443/why-java-foreach-doesnt-change-element-value). `x` is a copy of each element in `data`, it's not a reference to that element.

Comment: Use map() operator

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis i am using primitive type for the variable x, so reference should not matter.

Comment: No, that's not what I mean. The variable `x` is not the same variable as  `data[someIndex]`. It just holds a copy of its value.

Comment: @SergeyBulavkin could you show a map example of the above use case?

Comment: `map` would have the same problem unless you collected into a new array and just assigned that to `data`. The proper way to do what you're trying to do would appear to be `r.ints().limit(1000000).toArray();`, where `ints` created unlimited random integer, from which you take a couple and collect into an `int[]`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use an `IntStream` to iterate the indexes of your array.

```
IntStream.range(0, data.length).forEach(n -> data[n] = r.nextInt());
```

Or you could just generate a stream of random numbers, and create the array directly from the stream, using [`toArray`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/IntStream.html#toArray--).

```
int[] data = IntStream.generate(r::nextInt).limit(1000000).toArray();
```