# Why distinctUntilChanged() in RxJava2 prevent data with different hashCode?

Tags: rx-java2

I used `distinctUntilChanged()` to filter duplicate emittions in Observable.
But it filtered different emitted data. I used `map()` function before and after `distinctUntilChanged()` as below, and I found out just the before one printed logs.

```
 ..
 ...
 .map(t -> {
    Timber.d("hashcode: %d", t.hashCode());
    return t;
  })
  .distinctUntilChanged()
  .map(t -> {
    Timber.d("hashcode2: %d", t.hashCode());
    return t;
  })
  .replay(1)
  .autoConnect(0);
```

printed logs:

```
hashcode: -1015116098  
hashcode: -981267991
```

Why did not print any log with "hashcode2"?

Comment: What's `t` in both cases? `distinctUntilChanged` uses `Object.equals` and doesn't care about any `hashCode()`.

Comment: @akarnokd ,I override equals() and hashCode() with `lombok` library, so I expected as a contract when 2 instance of an object has distinct hashCode they won't be equal. Do I mistake anything?

Comment: Unexpected dataloss in `distinctUntilChanged` means only one thing. You have a mutable datastructure of which you manipulate previous items or you send only one reference over and over thus it is always equal to itself. That's why I asked the what `t`s are, what class, how do you provide them to the sequence.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In according to @akarnokd 's comment,

> You have a mutable datastructure of which you manipulate previous items or you send only one reference over and over thus it is always equal to itself

He said correct `t` is a mutable class that keeps some fields and a `List`.
I changed an item of the "list" inside a `foreach`. In fact my mistake was there :(, finally, I replaced `foreach` loop with an indexed loop and my problem solved.

[Some Q&A about loop](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15844468/2639542)