# Getting the first letter of a word in an array to capitalize

Tags: java

So I know that to capitalize, you need to use `.toUpperCase()`

Now I have a String Array, and in that array there are words, like `cat`, `bag`, `tag`, `dog` etc.

My goal is to capitalize them so that the array says `Cat`, `Bag`, `Tag`, `Dog`

The line of code that I am using and am being suggested to use is 
`String firstLetter = Character.toString(array[i].charAt(0));`

However, my program compiles, but crashes at that point.
Is this techinically the right way of doing this?

Comment: What is `array`? And why not just use `string.substring(0, 1)`?

Comment: sorry, I should write in that line of code so that readers understand, but array is the name of the array

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] with more context as to your code, its expected usage, and current output/crash message

Comment: @John With the current code I cannot reproduce this "*crash*" you're experiencing.

Comment: `array[i].substring(0, 1)` is the point at which the program crashes

Comment: @John `substring` is not mentioned in your question, please include all relevant code.

Comment: there is also WordUtils.capitalize(str) from apache commons-text

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `substring()` to get the 1st char and the rest of each string:

```
for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    array[i] = array[i].substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + array[i].substring(1); 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a for loop and modify each string accordingly:

```
for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    if (array[i].length < 1) continue; //in case there is an empty string
    String firstLetter = array[i].substring(0,1).toUpperCase();
    String restOfString = array[i].substring(1,array[i].length-1);
    array[i] = firstLetter + restOfString;
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15844443/why-java-foreach-doesnt-change-element-value

Comment: You can use just `array[i].substring(1)` to get the rest of the word -- no need to put the end index. +1 for having the only answer with a length check to avoid the inevitable ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Java 8:

```
String[] capitalizedArray = Arrays.stream(array)
.map(word -> word.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + word.substring(1)).toArray(String[]::new);
```