# For each loop with array list return sorted array but changing an a array list with adding a value is not returned

Tags: java

At first used for each loop to change the array list value by adding one ,next i created a tree map with array list as values and added foreach loop for sorting each array list but in the first case the values of arraylist not changed but in second it got sorted. why this happens

```
        
         Numbers.add(23);
         Numbers.add(32);
         Numbers.add(63);   
         Numbers.add(45);
        
        for(Integer list : Numbers) {

            list = list + 1;    
            
        }
        System.out.println(Numbers);
        //23 32 63 45

       Map<Integer, ArrayList<String>> map = new TreeMap<>();       
        ArrayList<String> mapValue = new ArrayList<String>();
        mapValue.add("48");
        mapValue.add("12");
        mapValue.add("24"); 
        map.put(0,mapValue);
        
        ArrayList<String> mapValue2 = new ArrayList<String>();
        mapValue2.add("200");
        mapValue2.add("130");
        mapValue2.add("110");
        map.put(1,mapValue2);
        
        System.out.println(map);
        
        //{0=[48, 12, 24], 1=[200, 130, 110]}

        for(ArrayList<String> list : map.values()) {
            
            
            Collections.sort(list);
            
            
        }
        
        System.out.println(map);
       
        //{0=[12, 24, 48], 1=[110, 130, 200]}
```

Comment: TreeMap sorts the keys. You have no reason to expect your value Lists to be sorted by it.

Comment: There are many topics required to fully answer your question. For first problem see: [Why does the foreach statement not change the element value?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15844443) (this question is about modifying an array, not an ArrayList but core of the problem is the same, assigning new value to temporary variable rather than to array/arraylist itself).

Comment: That is why it is better to [ask about one problem per question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/222735) so people could fully focus on it rather than having to also focus of things which they may also not know much about which may also prevent them from posting their non-full answer.

Answer (score 0):

- ***In the first case*** TreeMap sorts your data based on the key. Meaning you not sorting your ArrayList but you are just sorting your keys which are 0 and 1 in your case.

e.g. If you put data like this in your TreeMap:

```
Map<Integer, ArrayList<String>> map = new TreeMap<>();

ArrayList<String> numberList = new ArrayList<>();
numberList.add("200");
numberList.add("130");
numberList.add("110");

map.put(1, numberList);

numberList = new ArrayList<>();
numberList.add("48");
numberList.add("12");
numberList.add("24");

map.put(0, numberList);
```

TreeMap will order it in this way

```
{0, ["48", "12", "24"]}
{1, ["200", "130", "110"]}
```

Notice, The collection corresponding with each key has no change only the order of the `key: value` got changed (based on the sorting of the key)

- ***But in the second case***, You are traversing on your map and sorting the collection corresponding with each key. Meaning for key:0 you sorted your ArrayList and for key:1 you again sorted your ArrayList.

So to visualize, Before iteration of map your data looks like this:

```
{0, ["48", "12", "24"]}
{1, ["200", "130", "110"]}
```

After iteration 1:

```
{0, ["12", "24", "48"]}
{1, ["200", "130", "110"]}
```

After iteration 2:

```
{0, ["48", "12", "24"]}
{1, ["110", "130", "200"]}
```