# Questions about StringBuilder Array

Tags: java, arrays, stringbuilder

I'm trying to initialize a StringBuilder with "". These are 2 samples, the first one doesn't work while the second one works. Can anyone explain a bit more? Is this because StingBuilder is an object?

```
    for (StringBuilder element : sb){
        element = new StringBuilder(""); 
    } // this solution doesn't work, print sb[0] = null

    for(int i=0; i<sb.length; i++){
        sb[i] = new StringBuilder("");
    }
```

I'm expecting both would work.

Comment: Define "works". What are you trying to accomplish? What is `sb`? Please show a complete code example that we can copy/paste, compile, and run ourselves without any additional errors than what you are asking about. This means you need to declare all variables that you use and include valid `System.out.println()` calls rather than just a comment.

Comment: Also, if your question is about arrays, maybe you should do something simpler like an `int[]` to illustrate what you are doing rather than a `StringBuilder[]`.

Comment: Your first loop pulls an element from the array, then assigns the variable a new reference, so element now points to somewhere else, not what's in the array.  The second assigns the reference to the array element directly

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why doesn't assigning to the iteration variable in a foreach loop change the underlying data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15844443/why-doesnt-assigning-to-the-iteration-variable-in-a-foreach-loop-change-the-und)

Answer (score 1):

The `for-each` loop hides the iterator, so your first approach will not work. Another solution would be generating a `Stream<StringBuilder>` and then converting that to an array. Assuming you want an array of `n` `StringBuilder`(s) that might look something like,

```
StringBuilder[] sb = Stream.generate(() -> new StringBuilder()).limit(n)
        .toArray(size -> new StringBuilder[size]);
```

Note that a `forEach` loop over the array indices would also work

```
IntStream.range(0, sb.length).forEach(i -> sb[i] = new StringBuilder());
```

Answer (score 1):

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/85206/22390653) is super helpful and explains in detail about what `element` actually is in your first `for-each` loop. It's an instance of an [iterator](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html), not the actual member of the `StringBuilder` array `sb`.

Your second approach works because you are populating individual array elements `sb[i]` with value `""`.